# 404 Not Found при попытке загрузить CSS файлы. Spring

Tags: css, spring, spring-security

Делаю сайт на Spring-е с использованием JWT токенов и столкнулся с проблемой загрузкой css файлов. Смотрел в чем проблема и в консоли разработчика (F12) обнаружил проблему у style.css - 404 Not Found, что означает что сервер не может найти статический ресурс по пути.

При переходе на /login есть форма, но без стилей и вот ошибка в F12:
ㅤ
[image: ошибка]

Код SecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(
                    csrf -> csrf.disable()
            ).authorizeHttpRequests( (auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/main", "/add").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling(
                    exp -> exp.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            );
    return http.build();
}
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**");
}
```

JwtRequestFiler, Фильтр который проверяет jwt токен из cookie:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    if (ignoredUrls.contains(requestURI)|| requestURI.startsWith("/static/") || requestURI.startsWith("/css/")) {
        logger.info("Пользователь попал на игнорируемую страницу");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    // Достаём токен, далее нужно проверить, действительный ли токен
    String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String token = tokenExtractor.extractToken(request);

        if (jwtTokenUtils.validateToken(token)) {
            logger.info("Токен прошёл проверку");
            logger.info("Действующий токен: " + token);
            String username = jwtTokenUtils.getUsername(token);

            if (username != null) {
                logger.info("С токеном все ок!");
                UserDetails user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authorization = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        null,
                        user.getAuthorities()
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authorization);
                logger.info("Успешно положили в контекст");
            }
        } else {
            // Удаляем токен из cookie
            tokenExtractor.removeTokenFromRequest(request);
            response.setStatus(401);
            logger.info("Ошибка: С токеном что то не так");
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Структура resources:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки на css файлы указывал следующим образом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Так же пробовал MvcConfigurer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)